# CSF status shows failures but it seems working okay

Tags: csf

VPS with AlmaLinux 9 up-to-date. Webmin control panel.
From Terminal (ssh)
`service csf status`

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status csf.service
× csf.service - ConfigServer Firewall & Security - csf
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/csf.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-01-18 23:15:08 -03; 10h ago
    Process: 710 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/csf --initup (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 710 **(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**
        CPU: 423ms

Jan 18 23:15:06 host.hostname systemd[1]: Starting ConfigServer Firewall & Security - csf...
Jan 18 23:15:08 host.hostname csf[710]: csf and lfd have been disabled, use 'csf -e' to enable
Jan 18 23:15:08 host.hostname systemd[1]: **csf.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE**
Jan 18 23:15:08 host.hostname systemd[1]: csf.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 18 23:15:08 host.hostname systemd[1]: **Failed to start ConfigServer Firewall & Security - csf**.
```

> csf and lfd have been disabled, use 'csf -e' to enable

`csf -e`

> csf and lfd are not disabled!

These are the 'failed' lines:
Active: **failed** (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-01-18 23:15:08 -03; 10h ago
Process: 710 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/csf --initup **(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**

**csf.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE**
**csf.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'**
**Failed to start ConfigServer Firewall & Security - csf**

I'm receiving regular csf & lgd reports.

I'm asking what those failures mean and how to fix them.